# How to utilize the common image resources in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, embedded-resource, resx

I have several ASP.NET MVC3 and 4 web sites. All sites are using the same resources that are separate to a library. Resources are .resx files.
I'd like to use images from these resource in my html inside these sites. 
I wasn't using resx files before so not sure what is a good way to work with them. 
I think that I might create a service to provide right image from right resource file, but i guess there should be a better way.
My question is what is a good way to use these images from resx files and might be it is not really good to store images in a resx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One easy way to do this is to add a `FileStreamResult` action to the controller, which should return the image based on the resource key.

```
public FileStreamResult Image(string key)
{
    var bitmap = (Bitmap)Resources.Images.ResourceManager.GetObject(key);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/png");
}
```

Now you should be able to access it from your view like this:

```
<img src='@Url.Action("Image", "MyController", new { key = "Image1" })' />
```

---

An alternate way (which can be done using only the view) is to create a base 64 encoded string.

```
@{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var bitmap = Resources.Images.ResourceManager.GetObject("Image1") as System.Drawing.Bitmap;
    bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
}

<img src="data:image/gif;base64,@base64" />
```

A good way to implement this might be to use a Razor helper, to enable the more straightforward syntax in the view `@Html.GetImageFor(Resources.Images.Image1, "alt")`.

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetImageFor(this HtmlHelper helper, Bitmap bitmap, string AltText = "")
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());

    return new MvcHtmlString(
        string.Format("<img src='data:image/gif;base64,{0}' alt='{1}' />",
            base64, AltText)
    );
}
```

---

<sub>**Note:** The properties on the .ResX files should be set as follows (as normal for MVC projects):</sub>

- <sub>set `CustomTool` to *PublicResXFileCodeGenerator*</sub>
- <sub>set `Custom Tool Namespace` to *Resources*</sub>

Comment: Thank you. Is there any disadvantage of using embedded base64 encoded images in the view? would there any page load performance hit because of that? Is it easy for browsers to perform several small requests rather than load the page that contains all the images in html?

Comment: @Felix yes, that's a a good point.  Using base 64, the initial page load will have to load all the images before it can displaying; might also be a bit slower overall as it can't use gzip compression, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Felix also, the inline images can't be cached separately.  Seems like that approach wouldn't be the best, especially if they are large-ish images.

Comment: This is a good answer to the question asked, but I wouldn't recommend storing images at bitmaps and converting to png on the fly.  It would be best to store the images in png format and web-optimize the pngs ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with service to provide images i need