# How to access resources in a .net class library from web request

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource

Setup:
I have a .net 4.5 class library that embeds resources (e.g., images) for reuse by other ASP.NET MVC projects.  For example, the class library (named BlockTypesLibrary) has the following path:

- BlockTypesLibrary (project)

  - Static

    - img

      - Block.png

I set the properties of Block.png to be Build Action == "Embedded Resource" and Copy Type to Output Directory == "Do Not Copy".

Now in my MVC project I reference the BlockTypesLibrary.dll and I using Reflector I see the resources listed ok:

- BlockTypesLibrary

  - BlockTypesLibrary.dll
  - Resources

    - BlockTypesLibrary.Static.img.Block.png

In the template I have tried to access that resource in many different ways but can't.  For example:

```
  <div >
    <img src="~/BlockTypesLibrary.Static.img.Block.png" alt="Block">
  </div>
```

Any ideas how to make this work?  I also need to include .cshtml templates as resources in the class library.

Comment: what version of MVC are you using?

Comment: As I don't have a hard sample I won't post it as an answer, but I think you need to use the ResourceManager class to pull the named resource (your image Block.png) from the assembly as an object

Comment: @Neverever either MVC 4 or MVC 5.

Comment: AHA found an existing question that I think will help. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523098/how-to-utilize-the-common-image-resources-in-mvc and I think it gives you exactly what you need.

Comment: @DavidW wow I did different searches and that did not come up!  Will take a look and see if that works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a Controller that will load embeded resource image from another assembly.

**Library Project**

```
public class ResourceLoader
{
    public static byte[] Load(string file)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // load resource
            typeof(ResourceLoader).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(file).CopyTo(ms);

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static string[] Files()
    {
        // return list of embeded resource available
        return typeof(ResourceLoader).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
    }

}
```

**MVC Project**

```
public class ImgController : Controller
{

    [Route("~/img/embed/{*filename}")]
    public ActionResult Embed(string filename)
    {
        byte[] content = ResourceLoader.Load(filename);
        string mime = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename);

        return File(content, mime);
    }
}
```

**View.cshtml**

```
<div >
    <img src="/img/embed/BlockTypesLibrary.Static.img.Block.png" alt="Block">
</div>
```

Comment: I upped the vote count on this because it seems like an elegant solution to the problem.  However, I will not accept just yet since I'm having a hard time implementing this in my solution.  But that's because I'm using a CMS framework that overrides some of the standard MVC framework so I need to fit this solution within that constraint and so far no luck.  Thanks!