# How to load an embedded image resource in a razor view, both are in a class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll

**I have a class library project, and in that project I have a Home Controller and and Index action method and an Index view**

In the view I am loading an image that is in the /Content/eagle.jpg directory.
I build the project and reference the dll in another MVC project,

Now when I browse the Index action method of the Home controller I get the view, but the Image is missing, If someone knows how to achieve this please help.

> Note: I am setting the "Build Action" for image to "Embedded Resource"

this is code of the view

```
<h3>
This is Index
</h3>
<img src="~/Content/eagle.jpg" height="680" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to utilize the common image resources in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523098/how-to-utilize-the-common-image-resources-in-mvc)

Comment: I wasn't storing images in .resx file, images were in the Content folder, however I have resolved it by HTTPHandler and route handlers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I resolved it in this way:

```
@using System.IO
@{
   var dir = $"file:///{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}";
}

<img src="@dir/Content/eagle.jpg" height="680" />
```

You should also copy file to output directory.

Answer (score 1):

If your build action is set to `embedded`, you can try loading with this function (.net core 3.1)

```
public static byte[] LoadEmbedded(string Name, Assembly Asm = null)
{
    var a = Asm ?? Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
    var s = a.GetManifestResourceStream(a.GetName().Name + "." + Name);
    if (s != null)
    {
        var Buf = new byte[s.Length];
        s.Read(Buf, 0, Buf.Length);
        return Buf;
    }
    throw new Exception(Name + " resource not found");
}
```